# Decoupling capacitors upsetting 74HC74 output

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I'm using LM331 to convert 0-10V voltages to frequency and a 74HC74 sets the pulses ON OFF time more equal.
The circuit below works in simulation:

[image]
(left-click to enlarge)

But I tried several times with breadboard from scracth and have the following problem:
When I add C7 or C6 for the regulator, LM331 still works but 74HC74 outputs zero voltage.
So any cap between Vcc of 74HC74 and ground makes its output zero. Without any cap the circuit works. But I want to add caos to regulator and Vcc pin for noise issues. I find this very peculiar why it doesnt work.

What can the problem be here?[image]

Comment: Obviously decoupling caps are supposed to work, so you are doing something wrong, but unless you tell us (by a schematic and/or images of the actual implementation) what you are actually doing, we can only guess. My guess would be you mixed up some pins, or used something that is not a capacitor.

Comment: I made this on breadboard three times from scratch I couldnt find any wrong connection yet. Schematic? I already added the circuit and explained what I do.

Comment: I might add some photo from the breadboard as well

Comment: you added a screenshot of a simulation, in the majority of cases what people then actually have on their breadboard differs

Comment: What have you done with the other D-type in the 74HC74, have you tied its inputs inactive or left it to go unstable? Schematic? That's not shown on your schematic, is it.

Comment: I didnt tie any inactive inputs, Simulation model doesnt show GND and Vcc of 74HC74. So they are tied in real.

Comment: Could it be that the reset (R11, C5) is too fast, meaning the CLR is released before the supply has stabilized properly ? Try this by shorting C5 briefly after switching on the supply. If that helps you could slow down the reset by making R11 1 Mohm and C5 100 nF.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I just tried what you suggested. It doesnt help, same issue remains, the decoupling cap from Vcc to GND still upsets or zeroes the output depending on the capacitance.

Comment: Added a photo without a decoupling cap.

Comment: Am wondering if your +12 V supply powers up *before the 7805 regulator* powers up, causing grief to the flip-flop. Try pulling LM331 output (pin 3) up to the +5v supply with a single resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your divider pull-up on the output of the LM311 is only providing a logic high of
$$ V_{oh} = 12 \dfrac{4.7}{10+4.7} = 3.84 V $$

A more suitable value forR7 in the EIA12 series would be 6k8, which would yield a output high as,

$$ V_{oh} = 12 \dfrac{6.8}{10+6.8} = 4.86 V $$

Comment: If you are correct then replacing HC74 with HCT74 should also do the trick.

Comment: @sstobbe I did what you suggested. It works now.

Comment: The LM331 has an open collector output anyway so just use a single resistor to +5V.

Comment: Single 10k resistor to 5V regulator didnt work

Comment: It is also good practice to put a bypass cap directly across your logic IC (literally one leg of the cap at the VDD pin and one leg at the VSS/GND pin, at the cap sits above the IC)

Comment: Thanks I still didnt get how caps have such effect on treshold though

Comment: Without the caps the 7805 isn't regulating accurately so without the caps it may have been averaging low